# In text file, How can I parse multilines in particular pattern using python?

Tags: python, parsing

I've asked a similar question in the past, but I'm not good at it, so I'll ask you again.

Here is sample textfile.txt

```
    dummy01234567890
    0987654321dummy 
    -------start-------(It is possible to modify)
    text line1
    text line2
    -------end---------(It is possible to modify)
    12345678910
    qwertyuiop        
    -------start-------(It is possible to modify)
    text line3
    text line4
    -------end---------(It is possible to modify)
    ;p12309809128309123
    dummyline1235567
```

I want to parse

"text line 1\n text line 2"  → array [0]

"text line 3\n text line 4"  → array [1]

How should I source coding in python?

Should I use split function twice?

Comment: Show your attempted code.

Comment: We need to know which data is constant and which is not in textfile.txt based on which we can take a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is adaptive and simple enough for most needs.

```
state = 'init'
arrays = []
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if state == 'init':  # seek for start
             word = line.strip().strip('-')
             if word != 'start':
                 continue
             state = 'start'
             lines = []
        elif state == 'start':  # start parsing now
             word = line.strip().strip('-')
             if word != 'end':
                 lines.append(line.strip())
                 continue
             # end current parsing now
             arrays.append('\n'.join(lines))
             state = 'init'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to achieve the desired result :

```
text = """dummy01234567890
    0987654321dummy 
    -------start-------(It is possible to modify)
    text line1
    text line2
    -------end---------(It is possible to modify)
    12345678910
    qwertyuiop        
    -------start-------(It is possible to modify)
    text line3
    text line4
    -------end---------(It is possible to modify)
    ;p12309809128309123
    dummyline1235567"""

text_list = text.splitlines()
print(['\n'.join([text_list[3+i*6].strip(), text_list[4+i*6].strip()]) for i in xrange(len(text_list)/6)])
```

This will result in :

```
['text line1\ntext line2', 'text line3\ntext line4']
```